# Funky errors using MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

Does anyone know what these error's mean? I get this when I click a button to play a video (download over internet on demand style).

The problem I'm having is that my video plays with no audio. In fact the audio volume bar goes away completely on load.

I have the feeling it has something to do with these errors heh.

```
~~>>SponViewController :sponButton:
2011-10-26 12:52:04.212 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.222 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.258 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.269 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.293 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.307 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.340 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.351 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2011-10-26 12:52:04.442 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _objc_assign_ivar
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth

2011-10-26 12:52:04.453 myapp[2692:12e03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriverPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _objc_assign_ivar
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
```

Comment: Do you get these errors when running on the device, or just the simulator? I think I've seen errors like this on the simulator, but never on the device.

Comment: Interesting. No, just the simulator.

Comment: I suppose they're just frameworks that represent features that aren't reproduced in the Simulator-- looking at it, it's all hardware-related stuff. So I'd guess it has nothing to do with your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDA is an audio format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio).  Since the Mac uses different audio and video drivers, there have been certain situations where types of audio or video won't play in the simulator since it doesn't actually implement the full software stack found on device.  In this case, it looks like the driver for the HDA audio your videos use isn't available on Mac.

This doesn't mean your Mac can't play HDA audio just that the exact plugin that iOS is looking for isn't available.  So it just disables the audio portion of the video and goes ahead and plays what it can.

Historically you used to not be able to play YouTube videos in the simulator while they would work fine on device.  This again was a case of a missing plugin.  Newer versions of the iOS simulator have a stub plugin that translates between the Mac's abilities and how the simulator wants to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the mentioned frameworks in the build settings of your project?

To me it looks like the frameworks are referenced without being present in your binary.

To add the required frameworks you can do the following steps:

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Click the root item in the project navigator
3. Select your target
4. Go to `Build Phases` and expand `Link with libraries`
5. Make sure the mentioned frameworks are listed here.
6. If they are not present add them and rebuild your App

I hope this helps

Comment: Ok I thought about it again. If it works on the device then my suggestion is probably not what you are looking for, because if the frameworks weren't linked with your project, then it would not work in either situations...

Comment: Exactly right.  It is something that is now occurring when compiling on the newest Xcode.  For some reason the Sim is not seeing  correct frameworks for Sim

Answer (score 0):

The volume bar is supposed to go away - it's behaving as if it's connected to a crude line-out dock device.  Make sure your computer's sound is on, too...

As for the errors - I have a similar issue with my app, which despite getting a similar slew of errors, isn't having any real problems.  The rule of thumb is that if it works on the device, you're fine.