# MPMoviePlayerViewController movie plays without being asked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a problem using MPMoviePlayerViewController. I'm trying to initialize the movie on `viewDidLoad` and then play the movie on `touchesBegan`. But the movie initially starts playing and on `touchesBegan` it only shows the finished movie.

ViewController.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController;
MPMovieControlStyle controlStyle;}

- (IBAction)touchesBegan:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic) MPMovieControlStyle controlStyle;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

[self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];
[moviePlayer play]; }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                     pathForResource:@"my_moviefile" 
                     ofType:@"m4v"];

mpviewController = 
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]]; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:mpviewController];

MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];
// [mp setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
// [mp.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 263)]; 
mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;    
[mp prepareToPlay];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

If I put all the code in `touchesBegan`it works as expected, but the movie still has to load, but I want to preload it and then do something again when it finished playing.

Any clues?

Regards

Comment: Tim has a good suggestion below. You can check (by inserting a NSLog statement) if touchesBegan is possibly called during loading of the view for some reason.

Comment: did that, movie still plays, but if I touch it plays a second time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider putting your `[super viewDidLoad]` at the top of your `viewDidLoad` implementation.  This often causes unpredictable problems.

Also, just try adding `[mp pause]` and `mp.currentPlaybackTime = 0;` at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: still does it. Maybe I'll have to test on a real device, and not the simulator. It acts weird like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909121/funky-errors-using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Comment: `[mp pause]` did the trick, and it works only on the real device. It has no affect in the simulator. I guess the errors do something weird there...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `MPMoviePlayerController`'s property `shouldAutoplay` to `NO` when initializing the player.

From the Reference:

```
shouldAutoplay
```

A Boolean that indicates whether a movie should begin playback automatically.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldAutoplay
```

> Discussion
>
> The default value of this property is YES. This property determines
>   whether the playback of network-based content begins automatically
>   when there is enough buffered data to ensure uninterrupted playback.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
MPMoviePlayerController.h